# How to refer to a SELECT statement result table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, join, naming

I have two very simple questions:

1. what is name of a select statement result table in MySQL (a name that I can use in another select statement, for example in next line)?
2. how to naming that above table (in question 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was found. I must use views.

Answer (score 2):

> 1- what is name of a select statement result table of in mysql?(a name that I can use it in another select statement(for example in next line))

Resultsets will not have any name unless you define an alias name while executing.

```
select * from department dept
```

In the above example `dept` is an alias name for `department` table.

> 2- how to naming that above table(in question 1)?

There could be cases where you select information from a single or multiple tables and join together. For that whole set you can define an alias.

```
select 
  emp_id, salary, commission, 
  ( salary + commission ) as total_sal,
  dept.dept_name as department_name
from employee emp, department dept
  where emp.dept_no = dept.dept_no
```

For the above query you can give alias when used like:

```
select * from (
  select 
    emp_id, salary, commission, 
    ( salary + commission ) as total_sal,
    dept.dept_name as department_name
  from employee emp, department dept
    where emp.dept_no = dept.dept_no
) as filtered_results
where
  department_name in ( 'sales', 'marketing' )
```

**Refer to**:
[MySQL: Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: I know AS. my mean is not that.

Comment: you can use the alias name of the result set in your other statements as identifier.

Comment: it was found. I must use views.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you wish to create a from a select command in mysql? This should work.

```
CREATE TABLE fishTypes (type VARCHAR(100)) SELECT type FROM allFish;
```

Is this the solution you are looking for? Here allFish might have the schema 
`(number INT, type VARCHAR(100))`

Comment: would you please descript this line? what about my question #1?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand the first question. The result table from a select statement does not have a name unless you give it one, like I did above. You can embed a select statement in another statement if you like.

Comment: I write this line in mysql but it gave a syntax error. what is (schema) in this line?

Comment: You need to replace `schema` with the the schema of your new table and cols with the columns you wish to extract from existingTable

Comment: can you write an example?

Comment: it was found. I must use views. my mean(answer) is view.